# Умножение в столбце значений

Tags: python

Есть столбец var и stable. В столбце var значения, в столбце stable - ряды True или False.

Что требуется: взять первое попавшееся True из stable затем разделить start на var (вар напротив тру). Получится значение count. Теперь когда закончится ряд True, на последнем True, var умножаем на count. Получаем нужное значение.

А затем до конца проходим также по всем True, пропуская False, где start заменяется на предыдущее число. В конце концов получим итоговое значение.

```
start = 1000
df['count'] = ((df['stable'] == True, start / df['var']))
```

Проблема - это не работает, вторая проблема - каким образом вообще можно собрать var зависящее True перебором? Можно сделать что то из серии if stable == True, но есть же красивые решения без этого, посредством dataframe.

```
    var   stable   target
0   35.0    True  1000.00
1   32.9    True   937.00
2   35.3   False   937.00
3   35.9   False   937.00
4   35.7    True   937.00
5   35.7    True   937.00
6   34.8    True   911.70
7   34.9   False   911.70
8   34.9    True   911.70
9   34.3    True   896.02
10  35.5   False   896.02
```

Comment: Т.е. сейчас третий столбец точно соответствует тому, что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: А если в `stable` встретится `[..., False, True, False, ...]` - т.е. всего одно значение True в группе - как тогда расчитывается значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Векторизированное решение:

```
first_is_true = df.at[0, "stable"]

# булевая маска для нахождения первых `True` в группе (подряд идущих `True`)
mask_first_true = df["stable"].astype(int).diff().fillna(int(first_is_true)).eq(1)
# булевая маска для нахождения последних `True` в группе
mask_last_true = df["stable"].astype(int).diff(-1).fillna(int(first_is_true)).eq(1)

# расчет целевых значений для последних `True` в группе
tmp = (df
       .loc[mask_first_true]
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .join(df
             .loc[mask_last_true, ["var"]]
             .rename(columns={"var":"var2"})
             .reset_index(drop=True))
       .eval("var2 / var")
       .cumprod()
       .mul(start)
       .to_numpy())

df.loc[last_true, "res"] = tmp
df.loc[:, "res"] = df["res"].ffill().fillna(start)
```

Результат:

```
In [140]: df
Out[140]:
     var  stable   target          res
0   35.0    True  1000.00  1000.000000
1   32.9    True   937.00   940.000000
2   35.3   False   937.00   940.000000
3   35.9   False   937.00   940.000000
4   35.7    True   937.00   940.000000
5   35.7    True   937.00   940.000000
6   34.8    True   911.70   916.302521
7   34.9   False   911.70   916.302521
8   34.9    True   911.70   916.302521
9   34.3    True   896.02   900.549469
10  35.5   False   896.02   900.549469
```

PS в вопросе и комментариях у вас ошибки в расчетах:

```
In [145]: 1000 / 35 * 32.9
Out[145]: 940.0

In [146]: 940.0 / 35.7 * 34.8
Out[146]: 916.3025210084032

In [147]: 916.3025210084032 / 34.9 * 34.3
Out[147]: 900.549469071296
```